# custom module to display content (nodes and fields) from another database

Tags: views, database

we are trying to somehow show fields from nodes existing in a different drupal database than the default.
Eg. in the site the module is installed (drupal2) we have the following settings.php

`$databases = array (
  'drupal1db' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'drupal1db',
....
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'drupal2db',
...`

is there a way to override views so that it displays content with specific type "eg news" from the drupal1db and/or from both the databases?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely you can use a different db for a view. First create a custom module use [hook_views_data()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7) in a .views.inc file to define the fields of the external db. Once you have defined the fields and cleared the cache you will be able to select a different base table for your view.

With some custom coding and db_set_active() or views relationships you should be able to use both.

EDIT: Assuming Drupal 7.